# How to turn off the vibration, which happens when phone call is connected or the camera is turned on?

Tags: settings, android-10, vibration

I've seemed to turn off all the vibration settings, including settings for camera application, but it keep vibrating when I turn my camera on (by pressing side button twice), the same happens when I call someone and they answer the call.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Android 10
Phone: King Kong Mini 2
I use Microsoft Launcher.